# What is the latest realm object server AMI?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I need the latest HVM image. I see the following ids for us-east-1:

`realm-object-server-hvm-20161028   - ami-5dd48d4a
 realm-object-server-hvm-1477556996 - ami-69b6e87e
 realm-object-server-hvm-1474909717 - ami-80347097
 realm-object-server-hvm-20161027   - ami-d9f4aace`

I'm assuming it's `ami-5dd48d4a` based on the date string in the name, but I'd like to be sure.

Update: I just launched a t2.micro with `ami-5dd48d4a` and cannot connect to the dashboard. Appears the server isn't installed. From my understanding, the purpose of the AMI was to have the installation done already. Advice on how to start, stop, or install the Realm Object Server if necessary on this AMI would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue in the AMIs that we published. This has been fixed as of yesterday. The new AMIs are:

- ap-northeast-1 (Tokyo)

  - PV: `ami-63e04b02`
  - HVM: `ami-2fe74c4e`
- eu-west-1 (Ireland)

  - PV: `ami-d94414aa`
  - HVM: `ami-d84717ab`
- us-east-1 (N. Virginia)

  - PV: `ami-89022b9e`
  - HVM: `ami-47022b50`

Our website will be updated with this soon.

Comment: Hi, when I type in e.g. ami-63e04b02 I get a long list of products. Can I choose any of them?